# ubuntu 14.04 wired connection packet loss

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, network-manager

I am running 14.04 on a new machine and have been unable to get a stable wired internet connection.

kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic

network card: RTL8111/8168/8411

If I enable DHCP, it sometimes connects after 10-20 minutes of trying, and then there is high packet loss when I try pinging my router. If I manually give it an IP, it connects right away but still has packet loss when pinging.

The router and cable have already been tested on another machine. I have already tried the r8168 driver in place of the r8169 (same results).

Anyone know what I should try?

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:16:16:c7  
          inet addr:10.0.0.19  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:109082 (109.0 KB)  TX bytes:40578 (40.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2400 (2.4 KB)  TX bytes:2400 (2.4 KB)
```

`lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f7e14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f7e1e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7e1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device d817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7e10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: df200000-df3fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000df400000-00000000df5fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7d00000-f7dfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7e1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7e1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 3
    Memory at f7e19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 3483 (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7817
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

`sudo lshw -numeric -C network`

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10EC:8168]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: d8:cb:8a:16:16:c7
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.0.0.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Comment: I think it is a router problem or DHCP(eth0)-DHCP(router) conflict.

Comment: Disable both DHCP.

Comment: I disabled DHCP on the router and on the computer, but the problem persists.

Comment: Try manually setting the speed to 10MBit.  If that still has packet loss, change the cable.

Comment: I still get packet loss with 10Mbit speed, but I have discovered that I cannot connect at all with anything higher than 10MBit. The cable and router have both been tested on another machine, so they are not the problem.

Comment: update: you were right it was the cable. The machine I tested the cable with runs windows and I guess windows is more tolerable of low quality cables.